# VMWare ESXi free version 7 upgrade procedure without vcenter

Tags: vmware, esxi

I can't seem to find a procedure on how to upgrade EXSi v7 free version with patches.
The question is twofold

1. How do I find the relevant patches? The vmware site is far from user friendly
2. How do I patch the free version of EXSi v7?

Answer (score 0):

Look on this page ; https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/rn/vsphere-esxi-702-release-notes.html

Section: "Patch Download and Installation", you will find informations on how upgrade your esxi without vCenter.

I have done once, a long time ago, you should be sure you can log into your esxi, copy vib files on it, place your esxi in maintenance mode, execute your command. You should read the full procedure on VMware website to be sure.

You can also reinstall with a VMware ISO of esxi 7, it will ask you if you want to reuse your old datastores or delete them. https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.esxi.upgrade.doc/GUID-77D42D81-F47E-4FE9-B4B2-B15AB16C9C1A.html

Comment: Thanks! They really do it hard for free users